# What is the difference between DbSet<> and virtual DbSet<>?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

In Entity Framework Code First, when I declare entities I have to use DbSet<> type of properties for that. For example:

```
public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

Recently I've met DbSet<> declared as virtual.

```
public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

What is the difference? What EF functionalities is enabled?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public AppContext()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AccountType> AccountTypes { get; set; }
}

public class AccountType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccountCode> AccountCodes { get; set; }
}

public class AccountCode
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid AccountTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual AccountType AccountType { get; set; }
}
```

The virtual keyword on the navigation properties are used to enable lazy loading mechanism, but the LazyLoadingEnabled property of the configuration must be enabled.

The virtual keyword on AccountType::AccountCodes navigation property will load all account codes the moment there is a programmatically access to that property while the db context are still alive.

```
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
    var accountType = context.AccountTypes.FirstOrDefault();
    var accountCodes = accountType.AccountCodes;
}
```

While the virtual keyword on the derived DbContext class (virtual DbSet<>) is used for testing purpose (mocking the DbSet property), virtual keyword in this case is not related to lazy loading.

===== update =====

Usually we are doing the testing against the service / logic, for example we have another layer for the account type service as follow. And the service accepts the db context instance using some kind of dependency injection through the constructor.

```
public class AccountTypeService
{
    public AppContext _context;

    public AccountTypeService(AppContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public AccountType AddAccountType(string name)
    {
        var accountType = new AccountType { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = name };
        _context.AccountTypes.Add(accountType);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return accountType;
    }
}
```

And now we need to test the account type service, in this case I used mstest and automoq to create the mock class.

```
[TestClass]
public class AccountTypeServiceTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void AddAccountType_NormalTest()
    {
        // Arranges.
        var accountTypes = new List<AccountType>();
        var accountTypeSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<AccountType>>();
        accountTypeSetMock.Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<AccountType>())).Callback<AccountType>(accountType => accountTypes.Add(accountType));

        var appContextMock = new Mock<AppContext>();
        appContextMock.Setup(m => m.AccountTypes).Returns(accountTypeSetMock.Object);
        var target = new AccountTypeService(appContextMock.Object);

        // Acts.
        var newAccountType = target.AddAccountType("test");

        // Asserts.
        accountTypeSetMock.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<AccountType>()), Times.Once());
        appContextMock.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());
        Assert.AreEqual(1, accountTypes.Count);
        Assert.IsNotNull(newAccountType);
        Assert.AreNotEqual(Guid.Empty, newAccountType.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual("test", newAccountType.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that LazyLoad is enabled by default: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.lazyloadingenabled?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: So why virtual is necessary in testing?

Answer (score 13):

Note that in EF Core (currently 1.0 and 2.0) still not supporting LazyLoading scheme, so using with **"virtual"** or without does not make a different.

FYI. The scaffolding generate **"virtual"** keyword may be supporting LazyLoading technique in the future version of EF Core!

In EF Core 2.1 the developer team added support for LazyLoading.
More information is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading)

Comment: Elementary virtual means it can be overriden in an derriving class.