# It is necessary to have virtual keyword for DbSet in c#

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

I am working on a hands-on question which my Company has given me as a part of my training. The hands-on is based on the Code-First Approach of Entity Framework Modelling. So I have created the course class as follows:

```
 //Course.cs file
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks; 
 namespace Exercise1 
{
  public  class Course  
    {
        
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public String CourseName { get; set; }
        public double CourseFee { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        public String InstructorName { get; set; }

 }
}
```

and then i have defined the CourseContext class as follows:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Data.Entity;
 namespace Exercise1
 {
 public  class CourseContext:DbContext        
     {

        public CourseContext() : base("name=CourseConnectionString"){}
        public  DbSet<Course> Courses {get; set;}
        //public virtual DbSet<Course> Courses {get; set;}
        
    }
}
```

and then the CourseRepository class as follows:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Data.Entity;
 using System.Linq;
 
 namespace Exercise1             //DO NOT Change the namespace name
 {
     public class CourseRepository      //DO NOT Change the class name
     {
        //Thi perform operation like insert,update, retrieve and delete method.
        
        private CourseContext context;
        
        public CourseRepository(CourseContext context)
        {
            this.context=context;
            //last line
        }
        
        public IList<Course> GetCourseList()
        {
            IList<Course> result = this.context.Courses.ToList();
            return result;
             
            //last line
        }

        public Course GetCourseByID(int courseId)
        {
           Course c = new Course();
           c = null;
           c = this.context.Courses.Find(courseId);
           return c;
           //Implement code here
        }

        public void InsertCourse(Course course)
        {
            
            this.context.Courses.Add(course);
            this.context.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("Details Added Successfully");
            // last line
        }

        public Course UpdateCourseFee(int id, double fee)
        {
           Course c =  new Course();
           c = null;
           foreach(Course cc in this.context.Courses)
           {
               if(cc.CourseId == id)
               {
                   cc.CourseFee = fee;
                   c = cc;
               }
           }
           this.context.SaveChanges();
           return c;
           
        }
    }
}
```

and finally in the program.cs which is the main file i wrote the code as follows:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
 namespace Exercise1      
 {
      public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CourseContext courseContext = new CourseContext();
            
            CourseRepository cr = new CourseRepository(courseContext);
            
            
            Course NewCourse = new Course();
            
            // taking the details of the first course
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Course Id");
            NewCourse.CourseId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Course Name");
            NewCourse.CourseName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Duration");
            NewCourse.Duration = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Course Fee");
            NewCourse.CourseFee = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Instructor Name");
            NewCourse.InstructorName = Console.ReadLine();
            cr.InsertCourse(NewCourse);
            
            // get course list
            var resultList = cr.GetCourseList();
            
            
                foreach(var item in resultList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}",item);
                }
            
            
            // get course details by id
            Console.WriteLine("get Course Details By id");
            int id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var result = cr.GetCourseByID(id);
            if(result != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            
            //update the course Fee
            Console.WriteLine("Update Course Fee");
            int updateId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double fee = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Course tush = cr.UpdateCourseFee(updateId,fee);
            if(tush!=null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Updated Successfully");
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

**Now everytime i run the code of the tekstac console. I always get the error as follows: **

Failed TestCase Name :  Test1InsertProduct
Failure Message :  System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: m => m.CoursesNon-overridable members (here: CourseContext.get_Courses) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

Failed TestCase Name :  Test2GetCourseByID
Failure Message :  System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: c => c.CoursesNon-overridable members (here: CourseContext.get_Courses) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

Failed TestCase Name :  Test3UpdateCourseFee
Failure Message :  System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: c => c.CoursesNon-overridable members (here: CourseContext.get_Courses) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

I really don't have any idea why is this happening.

But when i use the virtual keyword for the DbSet Courses as this 'public virtual DbSet Courses {get; set;}' , I Don't get any error. My instructor has also not told me anything about this.

Can anyone tell me what changes when i use the virtual keyword ?
I really need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors that you have provided refer to test case executions. The virtual keyword for the DbSet is needed for that case only.

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079133/what-is-the-difference-between-dbset-and-virtual-dbset) to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to use virtual keyword. When you created the database context and model class for the table, then you must run migration to create the table in your database.

Comment: So it is completely okay, if i don't use the virtual keyword ?